# Google APIs keys changed and apis disabled

Tags: firebase, google-api

I have 2 projects (staging and production) on firebase and google apis console.

I was using firebase old console and I have project using the same name on firebase old console

**I was using Google APIs Keys for (Android , iOS , Server) and I enabled these APIs:**

- Google Maps Android API
- Google Maps Directions API
- Google Maps Distance Matrix API
- Google Maps Embed API
- Google Maps Geocoding API
- Google Maps Geolocation API
- Google Maps Roads API
- Google Maps SDK for iOS
- Google Maps Time Zone API
- Google Places API for Android
- Google Places API for iOS
- Google Places API Web Service
- Google Static Maps API
- URL Shortener API

when I upgraded my project on firebase from old console to new console I found that my tokens keys has changed to (Android, Browser, Server)
The **Android** key has been generated after I added android app on firebase console to generate **google-services.json** file

**Additionally  All my enabled APIs that I mentioned above has been removed and changed to these APIs:**

- Firebase Rules API
- App Engine Admin API
- BigQuery API
- Google Cloud APIs
- Google Cloud Datastore API
- Google Cloud Logging API
- Google Cloud Messaging
- Google Cloud SQL
- Google Cloud Storage
- Google Cloud Storage JSON API
- Google Monitoring API
- Identity Toolkit API
- Mobile Crash and Performance Reporting API
- Stackdriver Debugger API
- Stackdriver Trace API
- Token Service API

Currently my app is not working because the Token Keys has changed.

one way to solve this issue is to build new (ios, android, server) app with the new Token Keys. But I'll have to wait for Apple to accepts and publish the app. also we are working on some modifications I'll have to ask the developers to stop working on what ever they are doing now to go back to previous branch and tag to change the Token Key and verify that eveything is working probably, then continue working on their system.

Another Solution:
To set back my token keys with the existing one

I remember when I upgraded the Firebase Projects it mentioned that I don't need to change the SDK or anything to the code and I can change it later

but what happen is that all Keys has removed and generated new keys, also all APIs changed

**Did someone had similar issue? what did you do to solve it?**

Comment: What does this have to do with google-maps?

Comment: @geocodezip Because my issue is related to the google-maps, I've removed the tag

Comment: I'd to change the keys on all my apps an publish a new build to play store and app store and to my server because we don't want to lose our clients.  i am just curious because when I upgraded the new console they mentioned that I won't have to change the SDK now, and wha happened is that they removed the previous connections data to the apis and as I said it's like they build a new project on top and remove everything I did before. did someone had similar issue and what did you do (or should you do) on this situation?